# Counting users based on a user_dim.user_properties.key

Tags: google-bigquery

I am fairly new to Bigquery and can't seem to understand how to count fields based on unnested arrays.

I'd like to count and list unique users based on values associated with user_dim.user_properties.key called "persistent_user_id". At the same time I'd like to to set up a filter for another field in user_dim.user_properties.key called "status" with a value string "Active".

FIRST CONDITION:
user_dim.user_properties.key = "persistent_user_id", with this I'd like to count unique values stored in user_dim.user_properties.value.value.string_value

SECOND CONDITION:
user_dim.user_properties.key = "status", and user_dim.user_properties.value.value.string_value = "Active"

This query works for listing users based on "persistent_user_id" associated values, but I can't get it to work so that it adds the "status" filter set to "active". This is my query, any help would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT 
    MAX(user_prop.key) AS keyname, 
    MAX(user_prop.value.value.string_value) AS user_id, 
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS app_id

FROM `tableName_*`, UNNEST (user_dim.user_properties) AS user_prop

WHERE user_prop.key = "persistent_user_id" 
    AND (_table_suffix >= '20180101') AND (_table_suffix <= '20180228')

GROUP BY app_id
```

My query uses standard SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MAX(uid.key) AS keyname,
  MAX(uid.value.value.string_value) AS user_id,
  user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS app_id
FROM
  `tableName_*`,
  UNNEST (user_dim.user_properties) AS uid,
  UNNEST (user_dim.user_properties) AS status
WHERE
  uid.key = "persistent_user_id"
  AND status.key = "status"
  AND status.value.value.string_value = "Active"
  AND (_table_suffix >= '20180101')
  AND (_table_suffix <= '20180228')
GROUP BY
  app_id
```

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to work perfectly! Quick question, why is it necessary to unnest twice the (user_dim.user.properties)? It seemed to me like the data that I wanted to extract was inside the same array, so it is not entirely clear how this works.

Comment: You need some sort of is_active value and user_id in separate columns of the same row to do the filtering, right? UNNEST creates rows from array elements, so the "status" and the "user_id" values end up in the same column. Second UNNEST creates the second column for the same data. I think it's possible to achieve the same result without the second UNNEST, just doing some sort of aggregation and filtering on the result of a single UNNEST, but it won't necessarily be faster or more readable.